# Showing that $d\Phi =0$ for $\Phi=\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i}(\mathbf{x}) d x_{i}$

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I am given 
 $\Phi=\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i}(\mathbf{x}) d x_{i}$ 
and want to show that $d\Phi=0$ if and only if
$$\frac{\partial a_{i}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_{j}}=\frac{\partial a_{j}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_{i}}$$
This is how I started 
\begin{aligned}
d \Phi &=\sum_{i=1}^{k} d a_{i}(\mathbf{x}) \wedge d x_{i} \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{\partial a_{i}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_{j}} d x_{j} \wedge d x_{i} 
\end{aligned}

but I don't know how go from there, can someone please guide me? And how would I use the equation given to me above?

Comment: Hint: what do you know about the wedge product $\wedge$?

Comment: @giobrach I tried thinking of their properties but did not really get to an answer. I looked up this question and found that there is an extra step where $\sum_{1 \leq j<i \leq k}\left(\frac{\partial a_{i}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_{j}}-\frac{\partial a_{j}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_{i}}\right) d x_{j} \wedge d x_{i}$, but I am confused as to why we did this...

Comment: I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: You should watch more of my YouTube lectures :P

Comment: @TedShifrin I definitely should :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wedge product $\wedge$ is *alternating*, meaning that for all $i, j$ with $1 \leq i,j \leq k$ one has
$$ dx_j \wedge dx_i = - dx_i \wedge dx_j. $$
Therefore not all the terms in the double sum are linearly independent, some even vanish (when $i = j$): you are allowed to only sum over pairs $(i,j)$ such that $i < j$. 
$$d\Phi = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{\partial a_{i}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_{j}} d x_{j} \wedge d x_{i} = \sum_{i<j} \left(\frac{\partial a_{i}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_{j}} - \frac{\partial a_{j}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_{i}} \right) d x_{i} \wedge d x_{j}.$$
On the RHS there are now no redundant terms (indeed the set $\{dx_i\wedge dx_j\}_{i<j}$ forms a basis of the space of $2$-forms), and the components that appear in front of $dx_i \wedge dx_j$ are the *actual* components of $d\Phi$.

Now you may easily see the equivalence between the two conditions.

Comment: This finally made sense to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help